# Tikz: Node shape changes because there is a label?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I must be missing something big:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style = {%
    draw, solid, fill = black, circle, inner sep = 0pt, minimum size = #1
  },
  dot/.default=1pt,
]

\coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (B) at (1, 0);

\node[dot] at (O){};
\node[dot] at (B) [below]{$B$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is that the node without a label outputs what is expected (the small dot on the left), and the one with the label outputs a much larger dot?

Comment: If you tell the node to fill it completely with black color, it will do it. Just try it with `fill = red` and you will see a difference.

Comment: The node text `{$B$}` is a text _within_ the node, not a label (use `[label=...]` for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment of Ronny and my own one here is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style = {%
    draw, solid,
    fill = red,
    circle,
    inner sep = 0pt,
    minimum size = #1,
  },
  dot/.default=1pt,
]

 \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
 \coordinate (B) at (1, 0);
 \coordinate (C) at (2, 0);

 \node[dot] at (O){};
 \node[dot] at (B) [below]{$B$};
 \node[dot,label=below:{$C$}] at (C) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```